# Python pandas: find if string contains any of the row values

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

Say we have pandas dataframe:

```
                        Country
0                United Kingdom
1        Bosnia and Herzegovina
2                        France
3                 United States
4                       Ukraine
```

And we have a String for example like this:

`'The United Kingdom and France are both strong jurisdictions within Europe, boasting huge markets, stable economies, and a substantial political presence. They also play a major part in the European Union.'`

Is this possible to see if the string contains any of the values from Country column?

Comment: by _any_ of the values, United will match both United States and United Kingdom is that intentional?

Comment: yes even like that would work, but I would need solution for both cases for ex: if whole value is in string, or any single word from that value is in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can do this in a reverse fashion, where we extract all the matches from your dataframe that are present in your string, we then use those matches to look up the values in your original df.

```
the_string = 'The United Kingdom and France are both strong jurisdictions within Europe, boasting huge markets, stable economies, and a substantial political presence. They also play a major part in the European Union.'
```

---

```
pat = '|'.join(df['Country'].tolist()) 
#'United Kingdom|Bosnia and Herzegovina|France|United States|Ukraine'

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'string' : the_string},index=[0])
matches = df1['string'].str.extractall(f'({pat})')[0].tolist()
```

---

```
print(matches)
['United Kingdom', 'France']


df[df['Country'].isin(matches)]


                    Country
0            United Kingdom
2                    France
```

Comment: it seems like working, but can you please explain this line: matches = df1['string'].str.extractall(f'({pat})')[0].tolist()``

Comment: @IhorHarmatii yes - it extracts all the matches from your `pat` variable, which is all your values seperate by `|` in regex `|` is used as an OR statement. then pass all the matches back into a list to filter your orignal dataframe by.

Answer (score 1):

One way to start is by using an `apply()` on the sentences column - where you apply a lambda function that checks for what you need. You can read about `apply()` in [the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Here's an example:

```
# This creates the countries data frame
>>> countries = pd.DataFrame([{"country": x} for x in ["United Kingdom", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "France", "United States", "Ukraine"]])

# You can see the unique values in this data frame using values
>>> countries.country.values
array(['United Kingdom', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'France',
       'United States', 'Ukraine'], dtype=object)

# Example data with one example that should match, and another that should not
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"sentence": x} for x in ["The United Kingdom and France are both strong jurisdictions within Europe, boasting huge markets, stable economies, and a substantial political presence. They also play a major part in the European Union.", "this sentence has no countries in it"]])

# Apply a lambda function
>>> df["has_value"] = df["sentence"].apply(lambda x: any(y in x for y in countries.country.values))

>>> df
                                            sentence  has_value
0  The United Kingdom and France are both strong ...       True
1               this sentence has no countries in it      False
```

The lambda function itself is returning `True` if any of the values from the `countries` data frame appear in the sentences in the second data frame.

Note - this will not work if the sentence has a lower cased value such as `"united kingdom"` or acronyms like `"uk"`. Depending on your use case you may need to think about that.

Comment: but let's say were talking about dataframes that have 100-200k values, would you still recommend this approach? I mean 100-200k values in Country column